# Want to open command prompt when running a program in visual studio community

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

My visual studio community 2015 are opening a MFC program when I hit RUN. All over youtube, everyone has command promt automatically opening when hitting the RUN or Local windows debugger button. I want to change it to command promt aswell, does anyone have a solution?

(beginner)

Comment: Did you create a Win32 Console Application?

Comment: [http://puu.sh/lFpTn/be92b0156e.png]
Here is a screenshot of what i have done, hope it helps

Comment: You could also call the executable from the command line/VS command prompt. Just navigate to the out folder and call it when-ever you build. 

Sometimes it's handy to have the exact output in front of you when trying to go through the code (especially for a beginner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you created an MFC project and when you start this, of course you start an MFC program.
If you want a console application use `File->New->Project` and select the `Win32 console project` template.

See this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46e82t5z.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Okay, then i will try that.
Thank you guys for so quick answers :)